# Finding Subset of Polygon centroids Which Are Within A Certain Distance of the Centroids of Other Polygons in R

Tags: r, subset, shapefile, r-sf, nearest-neighbor

I am attempting to calculate summary statistics for the the administrative units within 5km of every administrative in a shapefile of Jamaica. I use dnearneigh() to find which administrative units these are, but then I am not sure how best to work with the list I get as an output to calculate summary statistics. I tried using spatial subsetting but that has not worked, so advice on how best to carry out this operation would be useful.

```
shp_centroid <- st_point_on_surface(sf_communities)

shp_centroid_coord <- st_coordinates(shp_centroid)

shp_dist <- dnearneigh(shp_centroid_coord,0,5000)
subset <- sf_communities[unlist(shp_dist),]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to go with nested *tibbles* / *data.frames* where every administrative unit has its own tibble of neighbours + itself. Thanks to rowwise operations in `dplyr`, collecting summary statistics from such structures is quite convenient. There's always an option to use `unnest()` to lengthen that nested dataset and go with `group_by()`/`summarise()` instead.

The following example uses `nc` dataset from `sf` package, distance threshold is set to 50km to better match those shape sizes. Instead of `spdep` package, it just uses `sf` functions, meaning that the list we'll work with (`sgbp` - sparse geometry binary predicate lists, standard `sf` stuff) might have a slightly different structure. Here the neighbourhood is defined as an intersection of 50km buffer and county polygons, not county centroids as described in the Question title; so this might be another detail to change / review.

###### Prepare example, test and visualize subsetting for a single county.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# example data from sf package examples
nc = read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% 
  select(NAME, AREA, starts_with("BIR"))
nc
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> # A tibble: 100 × 5
#>    NAME         AREA BIR74 BIR79                                        geometry
#>    <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>                              <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
#>  1 Ashe        0.114  1091  1364 (((-81.47276 36.23436, -81.54084 36.27251, -81…
#>  2 Alleghany   0.061   487   542 (((-81.23989 36.36536, -81.24069 36.37942, -81…
#>  3 Surry       0.143  3188  3616 (((-80.45634 36.24256, -80.47639 36.25473, -80…
#>  4 Currituck   0.07    508   830 (((-76.00897 36.3196, -76.01735 36.33773, -76.…
#>  5 Northampton 0.153  1421  1606 (((-77.21767 36.24098, -77.23461 36.2146, -77.…
#>  6 Hertford    0.097  1452  1838 (((-76.74506 36.23392, -76.98069 36.23024, -76…
#>  7 Camden      0.062   286   350 (((-76.00897 36.3196, -75.95718 36.19377, -75.…
#>  8 Gates       0.091   420   594 (((-76.56251 36.34057, -76.60424 36.31498, -76…
#>  9 Warren      0.118   968  1190 (((-78.30876 36.26004, -78.28293 36.29188, -78…
#> 10 Stokes      0.124  1612  2038 (((-80.02567 36.25023, -80.45301 36.25709, -80…
#> # ℹ 90 more rows

# test and visualize neighbourhood subsetting for a single county (Lee)
lee = tibble::lst(
  polygon = nc[nc$NAME == "Lee","geometry"],
  centroid = st_centroid(polygon),
  buffer = st_buffer(centroid, 50000),
  within = st_filter(nc, buffer)
)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc) +
  geom_sf(data = lee$within, fill = "green") +
  geom_sf(data = lee$polygon, fill = "red") +
  geom_sf(data = lee$buffer, alpha = .6, fill = "gold") +
  geom_sf(data = lee$centroid, size = 1)
```

[image]

###### Apply that same logic on a dataset

```r
# resulting within_dist type is sgbp, "sparse geometry binary predicate lists",
# a list of sf object row indeces that intersect with the buffer  
nc <- nc %>% 
  mutate(within_dist = st_centroid(geometry) %>% 
           st_buffer(50000) %>% 
           st_intersects(geometry)
         , .before = "geometry")
nc
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 5 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> # A tibble: 100 × 6
#>    NAME         AREA BIR74 BIR79 within_dist                            geometry
#>  * <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <sgbp[,100]>                 <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
#>  1 Ashe        0.114  1091  1364 <int [7]>    (((-81.47276 36.23436, -81.54084 …
#>  2 Alleghany   0.061   487   542 <int [7]>    (((-81.23989 36.36536, -81.24069 …
#>  3 Surry       0.143  3188  3616 <int [9]>    (((-80.45634 36.24256, -80.47639 …
#>  4 Currituck   0.07    508   830 <int [8]>    (((-76.00897 36.3196, -76.01735 3…
#>  5 Northampton 0.153  1421  1606 <int [9]>    (((-77.21767 36.24098, -77.23461 …
#>  6 Hertford    0.097  1452  1838 <int [10]>   (((-76.74506 36.23392, -76.98069 …
#>  7 Camden      0.062   286   350 <int [11]>   (((-76.00897 36.3196, -75.95718 3…
#>  8 Gates       0.091   420   594 <int [9]>    (((-76.56251 36.34057, -76.60424 …
#>  9 Warren      0.118   968  1190 <int [8]>    (((-78.30876 36.26004, -78.28293 …
#> 10 Stokes      0.124  1612  2038 <int [8]>    (((-80.02567 36.25023, -80.45301 …
#> # ℹ 90 more rows

# within_dist for Lee:
nc$within_dist[nc$NAME == "Lee"]
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] 27 29 30 37 47 48 54 60 63 67 82 86

# resolved to NAMEs :
nc$NAME[nc$within_dist[nc$NAME == "Lee"][[1]]]
#>  [1] "Alamance"   "Orange"     "Durham"     "Wake"       "Randolph"  
#>  [6] "Chatham"    "Johnston"   "Lee"        "Harnett"    "Moore"     
#> [11] "Cumberland" "Hoke"
```

##### Build a nested tibble

```
# ignore geometries for now for more compact output
nc_df <- st_drop_geometry(nc)

# build a nested tibble, each county row gets a tibble of neighbours (nb),
# use rowwise grouping to subset nc_df with within_dist of current row
nc_nested <- nc_df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    nb_idx = paste(within_dist, collapse = ","),
    nb_names = paste(nc_df[["NAME"]][within_dist], collapse = ","),
    nb = (nc_df[within_dist, ]) %>% select(-within_dist) %>% list()) %>% 
  ungroup()
nc_nested
#> # A tibble: 100 × 8
#>    NAME         AREA BIR74 BIR79 within_dist  nb_idx           nb_names nb      
#>    <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <sgbp[,100]> <chr>            <chr>    <list>  
#>  1 Ashe        0.114  1091  1364 <int [7]>    1,2,3,18,19,22,… Ashe,Al… <tibble>
#>  2 Alleghany   0.061   487   542 <int [7]>    1,2,3,18,19,23,… Ashe,Al… <tibble>
#>  3 Surry       0.143  3188  3616 <int [9]>    1,2,3,10,18,23,… Ashe,Al… <tibble>
#>  4 Currituck   0.07    508   830 <int [8]>    4,7,8,17,20,21,… Curritu… <tibble>
#>  5 Northampton 0.153  1421  1606 <int [9]>    5,6,8,9,16,28,3… Northam… <tibble>
#>  6 Hertford    0.097  1452  1838 <int [10]>   5,6,7,8,16,17,2… Northam… <tibble>
#>  7 Camden      0.062   286   350 <int [11]>   4,6,7,8,17,20,2… Curritu… <tibble>
#>  8 Gates       0.091   420   594 <int [9]>    4,5,6,7,8,17,20… Curritu… <tibble>
#>  9 Warren      0.118   968  1190 <int [8]>    5,9,13,15,16,24… Northam… <tibble>
#> 10 Stokes      0.124  1612  2038 <int [8]>    3,10,12,23,25,2… Surry,S… <tibble>
#> # ℹ 90 more rows
```

###### Working with nested tibbles

```r
# we can now calculate summary statistics by accessing nested tibbles in 
# nb column with purrr::map*() or lapply();
# or though rowwise grouping:

nc_nested %>% 
  select(NAME, nb_names, nb) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(nb_bir74_mean = mean(nb$BIR74),
         nb_bir74_sum  =  sum(nb$BIR74),
         nb_area_sum   =  sum(nb$AREA))
#> # A tibble: 100 × 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    NAME        nb_names          nb       nb_bir74_mean nb_bir74_sum nb_area_sum
#>    <chr>       <chr>             <list>           <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 Ashe        Ashe,Alleghany,S… <tibble>         1946.        13625       0.784
#>  2 Alleghany   Ashe,Alleghany,S… <tibble>         2092.        14643       0.839
#>  3 Surry       Ashe,Alleghany,S… <tibble>         3111.        27997       1.06 
#>  4 Currituck   Currituck,Camden… <tibble>          607          4856       0.576
#>  5 Northampton Northampton,Hert… <tibble>         2047.        18420       1.22 
#>  6 Hertford    Northampton,Hert… <tibble>         1293.        12933       1.05 
#>  7 Camden      Currituck,Hertfo… <tibble>          784.         8622       0.953
#>  8 Gates       Currituck,Northa… <tibble>          920.         8284       0.813
#>  9 Warren      Northampton,Warr… <tibble>         2366.        18925       1.08 
#> 10 Stokes      Surry,Stokes,Roc… <tibble>         5660.        45276       0.998
#> # ℹ 90 more rows


# or we could unnest nb column to lenghten our dataset ... 
nc_unnested <- nc_nested %>% 
  unnest(nb, names_sep = ".") %>% 
  select(-(within_dist:nb_names)) 
print(nc_unnested, n = 14)
#> # A tibble: 1,004 × 8
#>    NAME       AREA BIR74 BIR79 nb.NAME   nb.AREA nb.BIR74 nb.BIR79
#>    <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 Ashe      0.114  1091  1364 Ashe        0.114     1091     1364
#>  2 Ashe      0.114  1091  1364 Alleghany   0.061      487      542
#>  3 Ashe      0.114  1091  1364 Surry       0.143     3188     3616
#>  4 Ashe      0.114  1091  1364 Wilkes      0.199     3146     3725
#>  5 Ashe      0.114  1091  1364 Watauga     0.081     1323     1775
#>  6 Ashe      0.114  1091  1364 Avery       0.064      781      977
#>  7 Ashe      0.114  1091  1364 Caldwell    0.122     3609     4249
#>  8 Alleghany 0.061   487   542 Ashe        0.114     1091     1364
#>  9 Alleghany 0.061   487   542 Alleghany   0.061      487      542
#> 10 Alleghany 0.061   487   542 Surry       0.143     3188     3616
#> 11 Alleghany 0.061   487   542 Wilkes      0.199     3146     3725
#> 12 Alleghany 0.061   487   542 Watauga     0.081     1323     1775
#> 13 Alleghany 0.061   487   542 Yadkin      0.086     1269     1568
#> 14 Alleghany 0.061   487   542 Iredell     0.155     4139     5400
#> # ℹ 990 more rows

# ... and use group_by() / summarise() or just summarise(..., .by):
nc_unnested %>% 
  summarise(nb_bir74_mean = mean(nb.BIR74),
            nb_bir74_sum  =  sum(nb.BIR74),
            nb_area_sum   =  sum(nb.AREA), .by = NAME)
#> # A tibble: 100 × 4
#>    NAME        nb_bir74_mean nb_bir74_sum nb_area_sum
#>    <chr>               <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 Ashe                1946.        13625       0.784
#>  2 Alleghany           2092.        14643       0.839
#>  3 Surry               3111.        27997       1.06 
#>  4 Currituck            607          4856       0.576
#>  5 Northampton         2047.        18420       1.22 
#>  6 Hertford            1293.        12933       1.05 
#>  7 Camden               784.         8622       0.953
#>  8 Gates                920.         8284       0.813
#>  9 Warren              2366.        18925       1.08 
#> 10 Stokes              5660.        45276       0.998
#> # ℹ 90 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>